Can we use startswith for businessPhones in the filter in azure ad
I was going through the Azure User class. And in the User class for the attribute businessPhones i see the comment as follows
/**
 * The Business Phones.
 * The telephone numbers for the user. NOTE: Although this is a string collection, only one number can be set for this property. Read-only for users synced from on-premises directory. Returned by default. Supports $filter (eq, not, ge, le, startsWith).
 */
@SerializedName(value = "businessPhones", alternate = {"BusinessPhones"})
@Expose
@Nullable
public java.util.List<String> businessPhones;

This statement in the comment mentions that we can use startsWith on the businessPhones column. But when i try to use startswith i get the following error.

And also tried the other way like we use for Strings as below. But still get an error

Is it that we can use startsWith only for type String ?. Cant we use startswith for businessPhones.
Also have gone through this link
Filter users by mobilePhone or businessPhones in Microsoft Graph
The reason i am asking this is i have a method which dynamically builds my search query with the search fields passed to the method. The search fields being the attributes from azure user object
My search fields are as follows
azure.user.attributes=givenName,displayName,surname,mail,userPrincipalName,onPremisesSamAccountName,jobTitle,mobilePhone,officeLocation,preferredLanguage,businessPhones

And my code is a follows
private String getFilterQuery(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    StringBuilder filterQuery = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> searchFields = searchCriteria.getSearchFields();
    if (searchFields.size() > 0) {
        for (String searchField : searchFields) {
            filterQuery.append("startswith(");
            filterQuery.append(searchField);
            filterQuery.append(",");
            filterQuery.append("'");
            filterQuery.append(searchCriteria.getSearchText());
            filterQuery.append("')");
            filterQuery.append(" or ");
        }
        return (filterQuery.lastIndexOf(" or ") > -1)
                ? filterQuery.substring(0, filterQuery.lastIndexOf(" or ")).toString()
                : filterQuery.toString();
    }
}

SearchCriteria is my custom object and is as follows
    public class SearchCriteria {

private List<String> searchFields = new ArrayList<>();
private String searchText;

public String getSearchText() {
    return searchText;
}

public void setSearchText(String searchText) {
    this.searchText = searchText;
}

public List<String> getSearchFields() {
    return searchFields;
}

public void setSearchFields(List<String> searchFields) {
    this.searchFields = searchFields;
}

Finally the query is like this
"startswith(givenName,'" + searchCriteria.getSearchText() + "') " + " or startswith(mail,'"
                + searchCriteria.getSearchText() + "') " + "    or startswith(surname,'" + searchCriteria.getSearchText()
                + "') " + " or startswith(displayName,'" + searchCriteria.getSearchText() + "') "
                + " or startswith(userPrincipalName,'" + searchCriteria.getSearchText() + "') "
                + " or startswith(onPremisesSamAccountName,'" + searchCriteria.getSearchText() + "')";

When the businessPhones is part of the attributes and when the above query includes businessPhones like this it fails
or startswith(businessPhones,'" + searchCriteria.getSearchText() + "'

When the businessPhones is included should i build the query differently for that specific field.
Someone wrote a blog which i have mentioned in the comments section. Tried the way it is mentioned in the blog, but it did not work.
Getting the below error

The query that gets generated is this
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=any(t: businessPhones : startswith(t, 'avi')) or startswith(givenName,'avi') or startswith(displayName,'avi') or startswith(surname,'avi') or startswith(mail,'avi') or startswith(userPrincipalName,'avi') or startswith(onPremisesSamAccountName,'avi') or startswith(jobTitle,'avi') or startswith(mobilePhone,'avi') or startswith(officeLocation,'avi') or startswith(preferredLanguage,'avi')&$count=true

The only way it works is like this

Any help/suggestions please

Some one wrote this blog
https://indocoding.vesocial.com/dev/can-we-use-startswith-for-business-phones-in-the-filter-in#count-comment
But this also does not work

NOTE: The type of businessPhone property is collection of strings, it stores value like an array. Refer this MsDoc
As I tried to reproduce same in my environment, I registered one user like below:
Portal User's blade:

I used below command to fetch this user but I got same output:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=businessPhones/any(x: startswith(x,'a'))&$count=true
Response:

To resolve this error, Need to Ensure that the businessPhone value must starts with "a" for using $filter(startsWith)  :
Portal User's blade:

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=businessPhones/any(x: startswith(x,'a'))&$count=true
Response:

Reference:
BusinessPhones

I understand all those. If you see my question i have been updating the question with what way it worked. I already mentioned the way it works(refer my last screen shot). The question what i have is why is this not working  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=any(t: businessPhones : startswith(t, 'avi')) . I already mentioned in my comment above, that the answer shared in the blog does not work. What is the correct way of using startswith for businessPhones

Refer operator startswith from  this MsDoc
